# Why does `deborphan` list `cgroup-bin`?

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

Here's what I observe on my Debian Stretch :

```
$ deborphan
cgroup-bin
```

Based on the man page, this means no other package depends on `cgroup-bin`. Let's check this :

```
$ apt-cache rdepends cgroup-bin
cgroup-bin
Reverse Depends:
  cgroup-tools
  mininet
  cgroup-tools
```

The dependency by `cgroup-tools` is confirmed by :

```
$ apt remove cgroup-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  cgroup-tools
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cgroup-bin
```

1. Why do both `apt` commands (seem to) contradict `deborphan` ? Have I misunderstood something about `deborphan` or `apt` commands above ?

If I investigate further :

```
$ apt-cache rdepends cgroup-tools
cgroup-tools
Reverse Depends:
  cgroup-bin

$ apt-cache rdepends cgroup-bin
cgroup-bin
Reverse Depends:
  cgroup-tools
  mininet
  cgroup-tools
```

`cgroup-bin` and `cgroup-tools` mutually depend on each other.

2. Is this kind of circular reference something normal (or let's say "something done this way for a reason") ? I guess this is why trying to `apt remove cgroup-bin` actually removes both ?
3. Why anyway does `deborphan` list `cgroup-bin` ? If I actually uninstall it, I remove the whole `cgroups` utilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relationships between the two packages are as follows:

- `cgroup-bin` depends on `cgroup-tools`;
- `cgroup-tools` breaks and replaces older versions of `cgroup-bin`.

The latter aren’t dependencies, but `apt-cache rdepends` takes them into consideration by default; to only see strict dependencies, you need to run

```
apt-cache rdepends --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances cgroup-bin
```

which only shows `mininet`.

Your `apt remove` command says that `cgroup-tools` wouldn’t be required after the removal of `cgroup-bin`; this makes sense since `cgroup-bin` depends on `cgroup-tools`. If `cgroup-tools` depended on `cgroup-bin`, `apt remove cgroup-bin` would force the removal of `cgroup-tools` too (and ask you about it); it wouldn’t indicate that `cgroup-tools` is no longer required, it would say that removing `cgroup-bin` requires removing `cgroup-tools`, and both packages would appear after `The following packages will be REMOVED:`.

So all your commands produce the expected results, and there is no contradiction: nothing depends on `cgroup-bin`, so it can be removed.

The reason `deborphan` lists `cgroup-bin` as a candidate for removal is that `cgroup-bin` is now a transitional package: it doesn’t contain anything, it only ensures that `cgroup-tools` is pulled in; `cgroup-tools` is the interesting package. (You’ll need to mark `cgroup-tools` as manually installed with `apt-mark manual`.)